# Cannot get my endpoints list from controller in swagger UI

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to Spring boot with Swagger UI. I'm just trying to configure my Rest controller endpoints to show on swagger UI screen but it shows No operations for specs defined. Pretty sure, its a configuration issue.

I have tried @EnableAutoConfiguration, still it can't find the controller

```
SwaggerDemoApplication.java

package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwaggerDemoApplication.class, args);
 }
```

}

```
SwaggerConfig.java

package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;

@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration

public class SwaggerConfig {

 @Bean
 public Docket productApi() {
     return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.controller"))              
              .paths(regex("/test.*"))                       
              .build();                                           

 } 
}



TestController.java

package com.example.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@Api(value="onlinestore", description="Operations pertaining to products in Online Store")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test-swagger", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "Spring is here!";
    }

}
```

Expected: Rest endpoint
Actual: No operations defined in spec

Comment: Can you change for a test purpose Docket bean to have this configuration: ```.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any())``` .

Comment: try removing `.paths(regex("/test.*")) ` from SwaggerConfig

Comment: Do you have the annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(..)` in your code to enable Spring Rest Security? If yes, then your issue might be related to a bug in Swagger: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not your Swagger Configuration but your Controller is not scanned as Spring resource class.

Because your application startup class (Main class) has no `@ComponentScan` annotation.

So, your class should be like this:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwaggerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now you can access your API documentation from here `http://localhost:8098/swagger-ui.html#`

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` includes `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: Your solution is rather a workaround for the OP's wrong organization of the classes. It rather masks the root cause, which is a weird package placement of the main application class.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem like you and it was caused with the wrong placement of my `@SpringBootApplication` class, just like you have it.

(In the code snippets, I am intentionally omitting less relevant annotations, they still must be there as you have them in your post.

I also quote the words like "under", "root package" etc., as technically Java does not recognize anything like a "sub-package". All the packages in Java are at the same "level", even if the dots and the resemblance of the web domains "mislead" us to think about them hierarchically. However *Spring* extensively works with "sub-packages" and "root-packages".)

```java
package com.example.config;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {
    ...
}

package com.example.config;
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
      ...
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.controller"))              
      ...
}

@RestController
package com.example.controller; // notice that this is not "under" com.example.config where SwaggerDemoApplication resides
public class TestController {
    ....
}
```

I observed that if the `@SpringBootApplication` class is not in the "root package" of the `@RestController` class, it breaks the automagical behaviour and the package name set in the call of `apis(...)` is ignored and the package is not scanned. To be honest, **I am not very much sure** how the `apis()` is supposed to work and **whether it is a bug or a feature**.

To fix it without adding `@ComponentScan`, your package organisation should be something like this:

```java
package com.example.myapplication; // the main class is placed in the "root" package
@SpringBootApplication
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {
    ...
}

package com.example.myapplication.config;
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
      ...
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.myapplication"))
      ...
}

package com.example.myapplication.controller;
@RestController
public class TestController {
    ...
}
```

You may also further filter the API scanning by specifying

```java
.apis(
    withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)
    .and(basePackage("com.example.myapplication.controller))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in this way.
Path you specified can be the problematic.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("<your-package>"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API Documentation")
                .description("This API documentation is related <something>")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried configuring the path in various ways. Still endpoints don't show up. I can add you to my private gitlab repo if you have an account. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @AnirbanDutta my git account already linked with my profile so you can add me in your project.

Comment: Found the problem and posted the solution in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override 
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }   

   @Bean
   public Docket apiDocket() {

       Docket docket =  new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

       return docket;

    } 
}
```

**SwaggerDemoApplication.java**

```
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwaggerDemoApplication.class, args);
 }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

In Case you are using Spring Security you have to add below Configurations

```
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()  
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**")
         .permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: Can I share my private repo on gitlab? If yes, please provide me with your user name. Sorry I'm still a noob, couldn't get it working even after all the changes suggested

Comment: @AnirbanDutta which issue you are facing after above implementation, you can share your project as a public repo and can share the link

Comment: https://gitlab.com/anirban-dutta/my-rough-work let me know if this works